# Beautifulsoup: How can I parse the next <p.text>?

Tags: python

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="card big_card">
 <h3><a href=""></a></h3>
 <div class="clogo">
 <img src=""><span class="site"><a href="" target="_blank"                                                             title=""></a></span>
</div><p>telephone</b></p>
<p>address</p>   
</div>
```

and i coded this with beautifulsoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
for prov in soup.find_all('div', class_="card"):
try:
cur.execute("INSERT INTO provs (name,site,tel,address) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (prov.a.get_text(),prov.p.get_text(),prov.b.get_text(),))
print prov.get_text()
```

The first "p" tag is parsed, but I can't parse the second "p" tag with address.

How can I parse the next "p" tag as well as the first one?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO provs (name,site,tel,address) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (prov.a.get_text(),prov.p.get_text(),prov.b.get_text(),prov.find_all('p')[-1].get_text(),))
```

the right answer!